# ReportServer Database increasing in size. It's too big

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportserver

The report server database I have is over 300GB (note - its the ReportServer and not the ReportServerTempDB). The dbo.segment table has over 35 million records. I'm not so sure why its grown so big. At first I looked at snapshots and set a limit under site settings to 10 days instead of unlimited. This unfortunately hasn't resolved the issue.  Please can someone give me any advice on where to next look at?  Just for note the database on another server is round 5GB, where I would expect it at.

Comment: Every topic I find on this subject is related to SSRS 2008 or 2008R2; nothing on 2012+. Considering that 2008 is completely unsupported, maybe this is another reason to get that upgrade sorted as soon as possible? :)

Comment: @larnu thanks for your comment.  Unfortunately my company won't be upgrading for another year.  I just need some guidance regardless of SQL version on what might be causing this to be so high.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Umm, isn't the `Segment` table in `ReportServerTempDB`?

Comment: It's also in ReportServer

Comment: FYI: my reportserver database is about 2.3GB, the vast majority of the space taken is in ExecutionLogStorage (this is SQL Server 2016). Have you looked at the table sizes in terms of disk space instead or records? In SSMS click the tables tab/folder in your ReportServer database and hit F7 to open the object explorer details window.From here you can sort by the "Data Space Used" column and that should point you towards the culprit. Also check how much is reported under "Space available" in the database properties. If this is large then you might be able to just shrink the database.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the `ReportServerTempDB` database is fair game for deletion, so long as you can stop and restart the Report Server service while doing so.

> ### [Report Server temporary database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-database-ssrs-native-mode?view=sql-server-2017#report-server-temporary-database)
>
> Each report server database uses a related temporary database to store session and execution data, cached reports, and work tables that are generated by the report server. Background server processes will periodically remove older and unused items from the tables in the temporary database.
>
> Reporting Services does not re-create the temporary database if it is missing, nor does it repair missing or modified tables. Although the temporary database does not contain persistent data, you should back up a copy of the database anyway so that you can avoid having to re-create it as part of a failure recovery operation.
>
> If you back up the temporary database and subsequently restore it, you should delete the contents. Generally, it is safe to delete the contents of the temporary database at any time. However, you must restart the Report Server Windows service after you delete the contents.

You should definitely back it up before doing that, though... you never know what bugs lay in waiting.

The most likely source of database growth in the `ReportServer` database is Report History Snapshots. You can configure this via the SSRS management web interface in Site Settings > General:

- Select the default settings for report history:

  - Keep an unlimited number of snapshots in report history
  - Limit the copies of report history [number] (in days)

Or, alternatively, via SSMS via the SQL Server Reporting Service's Server Properties > History panel:

- Keep an unlimited number of snapshots in report history
- Limit the copies of report history: [number] (in days)

Comment: Thanks for your help @alwayslearning.  I've tried the limiting snapshots report and that didn't seem to help.  I assume there is a clean up job that works thereafter and this was done 24 hours ago (reporting services was restarted), and the size remains the same.

Comment: There's nothing special about the ReportServer database, as in it is a user database like any other. You can see which tables are consuming all the space by iterating over them with `sp_spaceused`, i.e.: `exec sys.sp_spaceused @ObjName=N'ActiveSubscriptions'; ...; exec sys.sp_spaceused @ObjName=N'Users';`